# How to return out values in Oracle Database server

Tags: node.js, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am new to this and was wondering how to return out variables in oracle sql without using print and dbms.output.putline I want this query to return value so that I can use it in nodejs like a select query returns value but for a stored procedure.

Here is the stored procedure query that I am  trying to run:

```
export const infoHR3 = async () => {
  try {
    const sql =

  ` 
  
  Declare
  ln_order_qty  NUMBER;

ln_in_proc_qty_hr  NUMBER;

ln_procd_hr_mass  NUMBER;

ln_in_proc_qty  NUMBER;

ln_wip  NUMBER;

ln_qa  NUMBER;

ln_packing  NUMBER;

ln_dispatchable_qty  NUMBER;

ln_despatched_qty  NUMBER ;

ln_finished_qty  NUMBER;

ln_balance_qty  NUMBER;

ln_bal_disp_qty  NUMBER;

  BEGIN

  CRMDBA.C1DVX007('9514593782','1',1,ln_order_qty,ln_in_proc_qty_hr,ln_procd_hr_mass,
  ln_in_proc_qty,ln_wip,ln_qa,ln_packing,ln_dispatchable_qty,ln_despatched_qty,ln_finished_qty,ln_balance_qty,ln_bal_disp_qty);
  
     END;  `;

     
     return await query(sql);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error.InternalServerError("Error!");
  }
```

Now the output is giving blank how do I return the out variables??

Can somebody give me an example of how to return out variables from a procedure?

Comment: You have to give us more insights what the query function is and where it is coming from.  Are you using node-oracledb package?

Comment: Yes I am usin nodejsng node oracledb package you can give an example of a normal stored procedure and how to get its out variables the connection is taken care of

Comment: Please check example given at https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#plsqlproc you need to bind your variables